# If $a \in \Bbb Z$ is the sum of two squares then $a$ can't be written in which of the following forms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

> Let $a \in \Bbb Z$ be such that $a = b^2 + c^2,$ where $b,c \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}.$ Then $a$ **cannot** be written as $:$

> $(1)$ $p d^2,$ where $d \in \Bbb Z$ and $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 1\ \left (\text {mod}\ 4 \right ).$

> $(2)$ $p q d^2,$ where $d \in \Bbb Z$ and $p,q$ are distinct primes with $p,q \equiv 3\ \left (\text {mod}\ 4 \right ).$

$(1)$ is false because $2^2 + 1^2 = 5 = 5 \cdot 1^2,$ where $d = 1 \in \Bbb Z$ and $5$ is a prime with $5 \equiv 1\ \left (\text {mod}\ 4 \right ).$ How do I prove or disprove the other option? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Honestly I haven't downvoted it yet (and don't feel to do it), but I will if you use swearing and harsh words on this site. There is no objection for anyone to downvote, unless they are doing it on purpose.

Comment: @Anonymous I am sorry to use harsh words. But for the last few days I have seen some persons in this site who are deliberately/purposefully downvoting me without any reason. How long do I tolerate it?

Comment: The sad thing is that no one, even moderators cannot see who downvoted on what question. If you want to find more information on this you should go to Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange and ask a question about it. I also think there are related questions about this fact there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the [Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) states

> An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no term $p^k$, where prime $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $k$ is odd.

For your $(2)$, with $p$, since it's distinct from $q$, then the power of $p$ in $a$ would be $1$ plus $2$ times the power of $p$ in $d$, i.e., the exponent of $p$ is odd. Thus, since $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then the theorem quoted above says the value *cannot* be the sum of two squares.

---

Note the Wikipedia's article's proof [link](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory/page/n145/mode/2up) to the Internet Archive says "This item is no longer available". I did some searching, but couldn't find any other link to it. However, there's basically the equivalent theorem stated in [Sum of Two Squares](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400twosquares.pdf) near the bottom of page $4$:

> **Theorem $6$**. A positive integer n is a sum of two squares iff $\operatorname{ord}_p(n)$ is even for all primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

It then follows with a remark about an equivalent statement (which is also equivalent to Wikipedia's theorem statement I quoted initially):

> Remark: An equivalent statement of the theorem, which we will use in the proof,
> is: $n$ is a sum of two squares iff it factors as $n = ab^2$, where $a$ has no prime factor $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

This statement is possibly somewhat confusing as it's basically the equivalent of saying $a$ is square-free. Anyway, the linked paper goes on to state & prove a lemma it then uses to prove its theorem $6$.

Comment: Would you please share some idea or at least provide some free online resource where I can find the result you have proposed to tackle this problem?  The wikipedia link you have given doesn't contain any proof of that proposition. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Phibetakappa Can you access the Wikipedia article I linked to? Regardless, though, as I state in my updated answer, the Wikipedia article link to the theorem proof doesn't work. However, I found another paper which states basically the same theorem and provides a proof of it. Please take a look at that if see if it answers what you're asking about.

Comment: I think you mean $a$ is square free. Right?

Comment: @Phibetakappa I wrote exactly what was in the other paper, but you're right, the implication is that $a$ is square-free, so I added that clarification to my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

There already is an accepted answer, but I wanted to point out a more self-contained argument. A way to prove 2) is to use the following elementary lemma: if $p=3$ mod $4$ is a prime and $a,b$ are integers such that $p\mid a^2+b^2$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, thus $p^2\mid a^2+b^2$.

This lemma implies that for any prime $p=3$ mod $4$ and any integers $a,b$, $v_p(a^2+b^2)$ is even, which shows 2).

Now, how to prove the lemma?

Assume we have $p\mid a^2+b^2$ and, say, $p$ does not divide $a$. Let $a'$ be its inverse mod $p$; take $b'=ba'$. Then $p\mid b'^2+1$. As $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, $(b')^2+1\mid (b')^{2\times (p-1)/2}+1$, so $p\mid (b')^p+b'$. But by Fermat's little theorem, $p|(b')^p-b'$ so $p\mid 2b'$. As $p \neq 2$, $p\mid b'$, so (as $a'$ is coprime to $p$) $p\mid b$. Therefore $p\mid a^2$ so $p\mid a$, a contradiction.